# Error "Exception: Cell reference out of range" on email notifications

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm new into creating macros in Apps Script.

The problem is: I have an integromat integration that takes some data to my sheet. Basically, every time my website is loaded, one row is added to my sheet, with all the cells from "A" to "I" filled. I wrote a function that, every time my sheets is updated, my function updates the columns from "J" to "L". Everything is working perfectly, no information is being lost. But very often I receive an email with the error

> Exception: Cell reference out of range

I'm trying to understand whats is going on.

I'm not a native English speaker, so I hope I made myself clear :)

Here is the script:

```
function PreencherColunasDados () {

var DadosLeads = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dados');

DadosLeads.getActiveCell();
DadosLeads.getRange('A1').activate();
DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();

var Linha = DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().getRow();

DadosLeads.getActiveCell().offset(0,9).activate()

DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();
var destinationRange = DadosLeads.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 2);
DadosLeads.getActiveRange().autoFill(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  
DadosLeads.getActiveCell().offset(0,1).activate()

DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();
var destinationRange = DadosLeads.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 2);
DadosLeads.getActiveRange().autoFill(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  
DadosLeads.getActiveCell().offset(0,1).activate()

DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();
var destinationRange = DadosLeads.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 2);
DadosLeads.getActiveRange().autoFill(destinationRange, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
DadosLeads.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();

}
```

Here is one of the emails that i  received:
[Email - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM0yb.png)

And here is a print of my script execution history, with two executions: [Script history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRP5B.png)
The first one failed and the second one was successful executed. But in the two cases my sheets were correctly updated and the cells were filled correctly.

Comment: I see no glaring problems in this script. I suspect the problem could be with another script that sends emails to you. Can you show that email script? And just in case, try  to insert `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush somewhere before one of the scripts grabs the data from the table and sends an email.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna edit the post and show you the email and the error